# What is the difference between these two derivative expressions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, derivatives

is there a difference between $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}$ and $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x})^{2}$? I have to tell if a differential equation is linear, and $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x})^{2}$ concerns me. If it's the same thing as second derivative, the equation would be linear.

Comment: Same thing; it means the operator $\partial / \partial x$ applied twice.

Comment: Is the notation $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ also used in the same text? If so, that would seem to indicate that the author intends for $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^2$ to mean something different, in which case Tom Au's answer below seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the notation $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}f~~$ means $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f)$, so $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}f~~$ 
and $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x})^{2}f~~$ is the same both you apply $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ twice.

Answer (score 2):

The first expression,  $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}$ is the second (partial) derivative, while the second expression,  $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x})^{2}$, is the first (partial) derivative squared.